# How to split the first 2 columns from the line in vim?

Tags: vim

```
 xyz mnl pqt aaaa ccc
 yz mn ats aa cbc ddd eee ggg
```

I have a file with each line like the above. Each column is split with a space. I want to remove all other columns except the first 2 columns, namely:

```
 xyz mnl
 yz mn
```

I tried a number of patterns but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

For a more Unix-y solution:

```
:%!awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

Where:

- `:%!<cmd>` filters every line in the buffer through external command `<cmd>`.

  See `:help :range` and `:help :!`.
- `awk '{print $1, $2}'` is that external command.
- `'{print $1, $2}'` is a short AWK script that prints the first and second fields of each line.

  For more information on `awk`: `$ man awk`.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly easy way to do it is to use the command `:normal` with a Normal mode command that would delete anything past the second field. For example, you could use `2f<Space>` to seek to the second space, followed by `D` (or the equivalent `d$`) to delete until the end of the line.

You can then use that command with a range, for example `:%` to perform it on the whole buffer, or perhaps select the lines with a Visual selection and then when you start the Ex command with `:`, Vim will automatically insert `:'<,'>` which means the lines in the Visual selection.

So, for example, performing the substitution on the whole buffer:

```
:%norm 2f D
```

See `:help :normal` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line

```
:%norm wwhD
```

Answer (score 0):

If a line in the file separated by a single whitespace character, then you can simply done the job using `:substitute` command:

```
:%s/^\S\+ \S\+\zs.*$//
```

The point here is that `\zs` to start matching columns you want to remove.
With `\zs` you don't need to save the first 2 words with `\(\S\+ \S\+\)`.